# PHP to customize the WP Fusion Gravity Forms integration to use the post author email as the Ontraport contact to update

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I am using WP Fusion to sync information from WordPress to Ontraport. We are using Gravity Forms in a unique way and need to manipulate the WP Fusion Gravity Forms integration to use the Post Author Email addresses instead of the logged in users' email.

I have identified the file that is handling this and can manually update the line in question with a hard coded email address and have it function like I would like however when I try to use `get_the_author_meta( 'email', $post->post_author );` it is not working.

Current line in class-gravity-forms.php - `$email_address = '';`
I tried to change this line to - `$email_address = get_the_author_meta( 'email', $post->post_author );` which does not work however if I change it to `$email_address = 'test@example.com';` it works.

The only other references to `$email_address` in class-gravity-forms.php is:

```
if ( false == $email_address && 'email' == $data['type'] && is_email( $value ) ) {
                        $email_address = $value;
```

and

```
$args = array(
            'email_address'    => $email_address,
```

I'm sure I am missing something and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Trying to modify any of the core plugin files would be fundamentally wrong to begin with - that change would get overwritten again, next time someone updates the plugin. Go check what _hooks_ are available to dynamically change the recipient address.

Comment: _“however when I try to use `get_the_author_meta( 'email', $post->post_author );` it is not working”_ - have you checked whether `$post` is even set in that place to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe I added
```
global $post;
  $author_email = get_the_author_meta( 'email', $post->post_author );
  $email_address = $author_email;
```
And it is working. I should be able to add this in the child theme correct?